# Asp.Net Web Form Role Authentication stops working a few minutes after publishing website

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an Asp Web Forms web site that uses Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin version 2.2.1 to mangage users and roles.  The default.aspx page only allows roles "Lab, Admin, LabSupervisor".  When the user logs in via the login.aspx page it redirects to the default.aspx page if the user's role is one of the 3 roles that are allowed.  Here is the problem...after I publish the website this role authentication works for 5 or 10 minutes.  After that, the users are no longer able to log in, even if the users' role is correct. After it stops working, the users try to log in, and the page stays on the login page and never redirects to the default page.  If I want the authentication to work again, I can usually republish the web.config page and the authentication will work for another few minutes.  I'm stumped.

So my latest theory is that my web.config file is becoming corrupt.  I have found that if I delete my web.config file and re-publish it, the website will work for a while, then stop working again.  This is my code allowing the 3 roles I mentioned and denying all other users.

Snippet from my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Lab, Admin, LabSupervisor"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Code from my login.aspx code-behind page:

```
protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValid)
            {
                // Validate the user password
                var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
                var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

                // This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
                var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(UserName.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);

                switch (result)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);

                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}", 
                                                        Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                                                        RememberMe.Checked),
                                          true);
                        break;
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt";
                        ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

One more clue...I am hosting this site using SmarterAsp.Net.  When the login page stops authenticating and redirecting to the default page, I have found that I can log in to my SmarterAsp.Net account and click a "Fix ACL" button and that gets everything working again.  No need to reload the web.config file, which didn't always fix the problem anyway.  But for some reason this "Fix ACL" button works every time.  I have adjusted my project file based on this article below, but it doesn't make a difference.
http://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a9/acl-was-altered-after-using-vs-web-deploy.aspx

## Solved!

I figured this out a couple months ago, but forgot to post the solution.  So it turns out, this was a cookie issue. I added the following code to my Page_Load event on my login page and it took care of the issue.

```
Session["DummySession"] = "DummySession";
```

I wish I could explain why, but this seems to have fixed it.

Comment: please post relevant code.